# Select statement waits even after applying NOLOCK

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I am explicitly locking a table as listed below:

Reference: [How to explicitly lock a table in Microsoft SQL Server (looking for a hack - uncooperative client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667186/solved-how-to-explicitly-lock-a-table-in-microsoft-sql-server-looking-for-a-ha)

While this lock is happening, I am running a SELECT query with NOLOCK on that table. But the query is not returing the data untill I stop the Window 1 and wait for some more time.

Why isn't `NOLOCK` working as expected?

--Window 1

```
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(300)
SET @TranName = 'MyTran';

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName


DECLARE @Current INT
SET @Current = 0

DECLARE @LoopCount INT
SET @LoopCount = 1;

WHILE @Current < 1
BEGIN

       SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount+1;
       PRINT @LoopCount

       ALTER TABLE DBATCPH ADD LockTest INT
       ALTER TABLE DBATCPH DROP COLUMN LockTest 

       WAITFOR DELAY '00:01';



END

GO 

Go
```

--Window 2

```
   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DBATCPH NOLOCK
```

Comment: If you issue an `ALTER TABLE ` command, SQL Server will acquire a `SCH-M` (schema modification) lock - and that is incompatible even with the `NOLOCK` command. No workaround, no way around it - you just need to know this and respect it. [See the TechNet docs on Lock Modes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for a detailed discussion

Comment: @marc_s. So, what is the alterantive for locking that table explicitly?

Comment: For as long as that `SCH-M` lock is in place, there is nothing you can do. You have to commit (or rollback) that transaction first.

Comment: @marc_s. Any other lock (other than SCH-M lock) that we can explicitly impart to a table?  This is to test a defect in our C# application.

Comment: Not that I would know of - the `SCH-M` is the classic case to disprove all those claims that using `WITH (NOLOCK)` everywhere avoids / gets around any locking - it does not do that ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you issue an `ALTER TABLE` command in a transaction, SQL Server will acquire a `SCH-M` (schema modification) lock - and that is incompatible even with `SELECT` statements that use the `WITH (NOLOCK)` query hint.

There's no workaround or trick or other query hint you can use, no way around it - you just need to know this and respect it. The `SCH-M` will be released once the transaction with the `ALTER TABLE` statement has been committed (or rolled back).

[See the TechNet docs on Lock Modes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for a detailed discussion – there are other cases (besides `ALTER TABLE`) when a `SCH-M` lock is acquired (e.g. when the table is being truncated).

The `BU` lock (Bulk Update Lock) can also prevent `SELECT`'s from happening - it will however allow other transactions to also bulk load at the same time (but it doesn't allow anything else).